# HTML CSS – Center image in left half of body

Tags: html, css, image, center

I am trying to horizontally center an image on the left half of the body of a web page. The overall width is 957px with a 15px margin between the halves which are 471 each. The right side actually has 4 rows of elements, but I have only included 1 row for the example. Those elements need to stay on the right half.

The images vary in size, so:

1. Any image with a width greater than or equal to 471px is sized to 471px wide.
2. Any image with a width less than 471px retains its original size and is horizontally centered in the left half (471px wide).

If possible, I would like to do this through CSS **without changing the HTML**, but I would also like to know the proper way that this should have been set up.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="full-957">

  <div class="left-471">
    <p class="image-box">
      <img id="image" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/social-bookmark/64/Photobucket-icon.png"/>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="right-471">

    <div class="row1-left">
      <span>
        ROW1-LEFT
      </span>
    </div>

    <div class="row1-right">
      <span>
        ROW1-RIGHT
      </span>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.full-957 .left-471 { float:left; max-width:471px; margin:0px 15px 15px 0px; }
.left-471 .image-box { width:100%; }

.full-957 .right-471 { float:right; width:471px; margin:0px 0px 15px 0px }
.right-471 .row1-left span { float:left; clear:both; margin:0px 0px 15px; }
.right-471 .row1-right span { float:right; margin:0px 0px 15px; }
```

---

**ANSWER**

```
.full-957 .left-471 {
    float:left;
    width:471px;
    margin:0px 15px 15px 0px;
}
.left-471 .image-box {
}
.left-471 .image-box img {
    max-width:471px;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
}
.full-957 .right-471 {
    float:right;
    width:471px;
    margin:0px 0px 15px 0px
}
.right-471 .row1-left span {
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    margin:0px 0px 15px;
}
.right-471 .row1-right span {
    float:right;
    margin:0px 0px 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. Just add this to your CSS.

This will give the image 100% width up to 471px. The margin will give the image 0px margin for top and bottom and auto margin for left and right which will center the image.

```
.left-471 {
    float:     left;
    max-width: 471px;
    width:     50%;
    margin:    0px 15px 15px 0px;
}

.left-471 .image-box img {
    width:     auto;
    max-width: 471px;
    height:    auto;
    margin:    0 auto;
    display:   block;
}
```

You will notice that I did not use the `#image` id you have used. This is because you indicated there will be multiple images and you cannot repeat IDs. For this reason just use img to specify any image that is inside the `.image-box` class.

http://jsfiddle.net/5uLus/11/

Comment: Hi Jonathon, thank you for the reply. I actually tried to do something similar but the image continues to stay all the way to the left. I added your code to my CSS and you can see the example at the link I just added as a comment to my original post. Maybe another class needs to be altered?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please see my jsfiddle. The main problem was that `.left-471` had a max-width but no defined width. You need to define a width for it else it will remain the size of it's content.

Comment: Ah, there it is. I also had to remove the max-width from the .left-471 class. Once I did that, it worked perfectly. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Test this CSS code:

```
 .full-957 .left-471 {
  border-right: 1px solid #FF0000;
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
}
 .left-471 .image-box {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .left-471 .image-box img {
        margin: 0 auto;
   }
   .full-957 .right-471 {
         float: right;
        text-align: center;
         width: 50%;
   }
  .right-471 .row1-left span {
       float: left;
   }
   .right-471 .row1-right span {
       float: right;
    }
   .clearfix {
      clear: both;
   }
    .full-957 {
       border: 1px solid #FFD700;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
   }
```